# overriding default syslog behavior

Tags: 12.04

With ubuntu 12.04, file /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf containes following line

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:*.*;auth,authpriv.none       -/var/log/syslog
```

Now I have my own rsyslog conf:

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/90-my.conf:local0.*      /var/log/my.log
```

However, when write to "local0" facility from my application, logs lines go to both

```
var/log/syslog and /var/log/my.log
```

How can I stop it to write to /var/log/syslog??

Comment: any ideas will be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer myself

for ubuntu 12.04 this should be done

```
local0.*    /var/log/myLog.log
& ~
```

Also this should be put in a filename that has smaller no. than 50 (50-default.conf)

I created mine as 20-my-conf.conf